# Where does this result come in use?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the following result:

If $(f_n)$ is a sequence of continuously differentiable functions defined on some $I = [a,b]$ in $\mathbb R$, and it satisfies:

$(i)$ $\exists$ $x_0 \in I$ such that the numerical sequence $(f_n(x_0))_n$ converges.

$(ii)$ The sequence of derivatives $(f'_n)$ converges uniformly to a function $g$

Then, $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to a differentiable function $f$, and $f' = g$.

I have never seen an instance where this result comes in use.

What is a situation in which this result is of significant use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a *really* important theorem. One consequence for example is, that a power series $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb N} a_nz^n$ is differentiable in its domain of convergence and $\displaystyle\frac{d}{dz}\sum_{n\in\mathbb N} a_n z^n = \sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac{d}{dz}a_nz^n = \sum_{n\in\mathbb N} na_nz^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

A result of this sort is also useful in verifying the legitimacy of differentiating with respect to a parameter inside an integral: for example, for $F(x,y)$ continuously differentiable on $[a,b]\times [c,d]$, 
$$
{\partial \over \partial x}\int_c^d F(x,y)\,dy \;=\; 
\int_c^d {\partial F\over\partial x}(x,y)\,dy
$$
follows (one way or another) from such a fact as mentioned in the question.